# Eclipse Java syntax coloring doesn't fully apply to SVN's checked-out code

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax, colors

I'm using Eclipse EE Indigo.
I made changes to the Java editor syntax coloring.
The changes are perfectly applied to newly created projects through eclipse, but when I check out projects from SVN, it seems like the syntax coloring is partially applied.

For instance, I set the class syntax coloring to Cyan. In a newly created project - works just fine. When I check out another project in SVN, classes syntax coloring stays black.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you made the mistake of checking the project settings into SVN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It seems that when I checked out the project from SVN, it did not import it to the workspace as an Eclipse Java project and therefore didn't have the classpath defined. Now that I corrected it and imported the project as it should be, I get all the syntax colors working as they should be.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the syntax is not being applied on newly checked out projects.
Try one of the following:

- From the root of the newly checked out project right-click -> Refresh

If still didn't help:

1. Relaunch *eclipse*
2. check again the applied syntax settings

Comment: Did you: (root of the newly checked out project) right-click -> properties and here specify again your syntaxes

Comment: When right clicking the root project and selecting Properties, I don't see any option related to Editor's syntax coloring. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: In the Java Editor actions, but I don't know if it can be done from here, if no, then there is a bug in eclipse. there must be some sort of refresh, because whats the deference between a created project and a checked out project. this makes no sense. relaunch of the project must do...